# Cannot filter between two columns by its column value

Tags: java, hbase

I am using hbase to store data. I want to filter data between two column values. I tried to fetch data from hbase, Couldn't do it. how can i do it?

Column family is `column_cf`
Column name is `column_id`

I stored `column_id` as string in hbase column.
I tried to filter using `SingleColumnValueFilter` with operator such as greater and lesser than comparator.

Below code is not working!

```
long a = 1111111111;
long b = 2222222222;
SingleColumnValueFilter startFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("column_cf"), Bytes.toBytes("column_id"), CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(a)));
SingleColumnValueFilter endFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("column_cf"), Bytes.toBytes("column_id"), CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(b)));
FilterList filterbyData = new FilterList();
filterbyData.addFilter(startFilter);
filterbyData.addFilter(endFilter);
scan.setFilter(filterbyData);
```

Data in hbase is : "1234567890","1010101010","1112345321",.......,"2324334242".
I need to get data between "1111111111" and "2222222222" without changing data type.

NO ERROR MESSAGE IS COMING, NO DATA IS FETCHING

Comment: From your question it is not clear to me what you referred to as data. Is it the column value that you store in a cell or the rowkey?

Comment: `column_cf` is very long for a column family name; you should only really have a maximum of three different column families per table, so why not just `c`? It saves file space which in turn makes queries faster.

Comment: @sompet : data means values stored in column value(cell)

Comment: @BenWatson Thank you for your advise. I will look in to it. will this affect filtering?

Comment: @HishamU yes filtering will also be faster.